# Passing values through objects in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass object from one activity to another in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

I want to know is it feasible and suggested to pass values from one activity to another via objects, also when Should I pass the values before calling the Intent or after?

Comment: You can but object must be `serializable`.

Comment: You can use appSingleton class with getter and setters of the objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it feasible and suggested to pass values from one activity to another via objects?

=> Yes its feasible and possible. Check: [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

> when Should I pass the values before calling the Intent or after?

=> Yes ofcourse you should pass object before starting next activity. I am amazed why you want to pass it after calling the intent?

Comment: No I was confused as to where exactly Should I pass the Value. After or before. Thanks Mate :)

Comment: And I was talking of the good old Dot method of passing values.